# Android: Content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-activity

I have tired every possible solution online (including Stackoverflow) to fix this error, however nothing works any help would be much appreciated.

#### What is the Error?

java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

**Note:** There is many answers on stack overflow and I have tired them all.

#### What do I have in my Code?

**XML:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />


<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

<ListView

    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"/>
```

**Code:**

```
 @SuppressLint("NewApi") public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mDrawerList = (ListView) this.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Anyone know how to fix this error?

Complete logcat report

```
09-19 14:53:00.376: E/MainActivity(28935): Error in creating fragment
09-19 14:53:00.387: D/AndroidRuntime(28935): Shutting down VM
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935): Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 28935
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:344)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:941)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:556)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1243)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5969)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
09-19 14:53:00.394: E/AndroidRuntime(28935):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: You need the id of your ListView to be `@android:id/list`, because you're using a ListActivity or a ListFragment. Also, your findView... is not needed.

Comment: Please post the actual `R.layout.activity_main` resource files, in every one of your `res/layout/` and `res/layout-.../` directories.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare - I added that to the question.

Answer (score -1):

do not use android.R.id.list instead use R.id.list.
Sorry for previous half answer but @android:id/list is specific to ListActivity and ListFragment from documentation:

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single,
>   full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire,
>   you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout
>   with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST
>   contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if
>   it's in code)

so either use @+id/list and then R.id.list or extend your Activity with ListActivity
Generally +id is used to create the new id in R while android:id is used in xml to customize with our own view as mentioned in the documentation.
Hence I am saying @android:id/list is specific to ListActivity and ListFragment.

Comment: I still get the same error using R.id.list, as in my question I have tired every possible solution its a complete pain in the neck

Comment: but you need to change in xml file as well

Comment: Also I deleted R.Java and regenerated it in case that was an issue, but nothing works

Comment: Deleting R.Java is of no use....make the change in your layout file..that is change the id of listview to android:id="@+id/list" or change your Activity to ListActivity

Comment: I tired that still error remains, I got the same solution you proposed in another stackoverflow answer, no idea why its not working

Comment: Please make sure you are making changes in both places in XML and class file as well

Comment: Yes I have in XML and the Class

Comment: XML: android:id="@+id/list"
CLASS: mDrawerList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list);   -  Im using those, and im getting the same error

Comment: I have doubt as per question What is the Error?

java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'    .............then if you are not using android.R.id.list anywhere how you are getting same error no

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
09-19 14:54:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(31416):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)

Comment: can you do a favor by posting complete logcat report in question itself

Comment: From the error report I could see you are using ListFragment...the layout file which you are inflating for that ListFragment must have a ListView with id @android:id/list for more explanation you can refer-http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

Answer (score -1):

simply jusr remove one line from your MainActivity
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);